# Polybase SQL Server 2019 in Container to SQL Server 2019 OnPremise - Insert into external table not working

Tags: export, polybase, sql-server-2019

I have SQL Server 2019 in Docker Container with polybase enabled and I am connecting to SQL Server 2019 On Premise with polybase enabled. I created external table in Docker -SQL Server.

I also allowed polybase export, restarted the on-premise sql server 2019.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'allow polybase export', 1;  
RECONFIGURE
```

SELECT works fine. but when I try to Insert

```
INSERT INTO Student 
select 3, 'Amaya', 'A+'
```

Error:

> Started executing query at Line 53
>   Msg 46519, Level 16, State 16, Line
>   DML Operations are not supported with external tables.
>   Total execution time: 00:00:00.107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External tables are read only. As the error tells you, you can't perform DML write-operations (such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc) on them.

This is also documented in the article [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (Transact-SQL): Limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-and-restrictions):

> Only these Data Definition Language (DDL) statements are allowed on external
>
> tables:
>
> - CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE
> - CREATE STATISTICS and DROP STATISTICS
> - CREATE VIEW and DROP VIEW
>
> Constructs and operations **not supported**:
>
> - The DEFAULT constraint on external table columns
> - **Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations of delete, insert, and update**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thank you for answering,  What is this Export option given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-hadoop?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Are you specifically using Hadoop? Also, notice that the supported version is *"SQL Server **(Windows only)**"* @Priya . You state in your question you are using Docker and that's where you created the external table. Docker is not Windows.